# Pandas DataFrame - Got multiple values for argument 'columns'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I created the following pandas `dataframe`:

```
data = pandas.DataFrame(
    ["2020-01-01", 2, 4, 1, 3], 
    ["2020-01-02", 3, 5, 2, 3], 
    ["2020-01-03", 4, 6, 3, 5], 
    ["2020-01-04", 5, 7, 4, 6], 
    ["2020-01-05", 6, 8, 5, 7], 
    columns = ["Date", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close"])

data["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["Date"])
data.info()

data.set_index("Date", inplace = True)
data.info()
```

But I get the error:

```
DataFrame.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'columns'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You need to give the data as a single argument of a list of lists... `[["2020-01-01", 2, 4, 1, 3], ...]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
data = pd.DataFrame(
    [["2020-01-01", 2, 4, 1, 3], 
    ["2020-01-02", 3, 5, 2, 3], 
    ["2020-01-03", 4, 6, 3, 5], 
    ["2020-01-04", 5, 7, 4, 6], 
    ["2020-01-05", 6, 8, 5, 7]], 
    columns = ["Date", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close"])
```